# How can I use setDisplayEdges() for multi-model loading?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk

I would like to turn the BIM edges on for all models. I have set `setDisplayEdges(true)` during the initialization of the viewer as well as adding `isAEC: true` to the options in loadModel().

Unfortunately, this **does not** display the edges.

How do you recommend turning on the edges for multi-model loading?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which model format your road model is, but passing the `createWireframe: true` option should help turn on the model edges with my research.

```js
viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc, bubble, {createWireframe: true, keepCurrentModels: true})
```

Comment: I would actually like to turn the edges on, not turn them off. Would that change your answer?

Comment: Sorry for my typo, the above code snippet is for turning on the edge. To turn off the edge is to set `createWireframe: false`.